# 3001: Invalid argument

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016, access-data-project

[The image shows the actual error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSbGt.png)I am using this following code for creating an audit trail in MS-access using vba script, but getting 3001 : Invalid argument error. I have already checked the table names field names etc. But couldn't solve the issue.
Can someone please help?

I tried looking up the 3001 : invalid argument, but I can not determine exactly what is causing the problem in my scenario.

I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me out with this.

```
Public Function AuditChanges(RecordID As String, UserAction As String)
On Error GoTo auditerr

Dim DB As Database
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim clt As Control
Dim UserLogin As String

Set DB = CurrentDb
Set rst = DB.OpenRecordset("select * from audit", adOpenDynamic)

UserLogin = Environ("UserName")
Select Case UserAction
    Case "new"
        With rst
            .AddNew
            ![DateTime] = Now()
            !UserName = UserLogin
            !FormName = ScreenActiveForm.Name
            !Action = UserAction
            !RecordID = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(RecordID).Value
            .Update

         End With

    Case "Delete"
        With rst
            .AddNew
            ![DateTime] = Now()
            !UserName = UserLogin
            !FormName = ScreenActiveForm.Name
            !Action = UserAction
            !RecordID = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(RecordID).Value
            .Update

        End With

    Case "Edit"
        For Each clt In Screen.ActiveForm.Controls
            If (clt.ControlType = acTextBox _
                Or clt.ControlType = acComboBox) Then
                If Nz(clt.Value) <> Nz(clt.OldValue) Then
                With rst
                    .AddNew
                    ![DateTime] = Now()
                    !UserName = UserLogin
                    !FormName = ScreenActiveForm.Name
                    !Action = UserAction
                    !RecordID = Screen.ActiveForm.Controls(RecordID).Value
                    !FieldName = clt.ControlSource
                    !OldValue = clt.OldValue
                    !newvalue = clt.Value
                    .Update
                End With
            End If
        End If

    Next clt

End Select

rst.Close
DB.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set DB = Nothing
auditerr:
MsgBox Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
Exit Function

End Function
```

Thank you,
Rito

Comment: In which line does the error appear? That would be helpful. Set a breackpoint and debug the code with F8 and look where he jumps to `auditerr`. But I think you have `!FromName = ScreenActiveForm.Name` replace it with `!FormName = Screen.ActiveForm.Name`. Or even better would be `!FormName = Me.Name`. This mistake appear more often in your code.

Comment: I see that I'm facing the following error.

Comment: Perfect... yes this worked.. thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`Set rst = DB.OpenRecordset("select * from audit", dbOpenDynaset)`